# Unable to restore MongoDB After Dropping

Tags: mongodb

Is there anyway I can restore the MongoDB after dropping with no backup.

We tried finding any auto backups with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Dropping databases in MongoDB results in the data files getting deleted immediately in both MMAPv1 and WiredTiger. There is no auto-backup feature in MongoDB, so unfortunately your data is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can't restore without any backups in MongoDB. there is no any auto backup options in mongoDB. If you want auto back follow this instructions [easy-automatic-nightly-backups-for-mongodb](https://coderwall.com/p/hdmmnq/easy-automatic-nightly-backups-for-mongodb)

[backup-and-restore-tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/)